# How to Remove the BRAND from WooCommerce Product Pages

Tags: woocommerce, metadata, hook-woocommerce

I need to remove the BRAND (meta-brand) only on the product pages. Can someone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzOfO.png)

Answer (score 0):

In general, to remove these elements is done from the theme settings, you can choose to use the property: ** display: none; ** to hide it. For this you must inspect with the browser and see where that property can be applied. If it helps you do it with css and you don't know how you can send the link to help you.